# A matrix is normal, if and only if?

Tags: matrices

Let $A \in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Let $\langle \; \cdot\; , \; \cdot\;  \rangle$ be the standard inner product in $ \mathbb C^n$, viewed either as row vectors or as column vectors.

Let $r_j$ be the $j$-th row of A, and let $c_j$ be the $j$-th column of $A$.

Show that A is normal, if and only if $\langle r_i,r_j\rangle$ = $\langle c_j,c_i \rangle$, for all $i$, $j$, $1 \le i$, $j \le n$.

---

I do know that $A$ is normal iff $AA^*$ = $A^*A$.
But how can I evaluate the ij-th component of those two equal matrices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is helpful in general to interpret $A^*A$ as the [Gramian matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) of the columns of $A$. Likewise $AA^*$ is the Gramian matrix of the rows of $A$. So if $A$ is normal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $i$th row of the matrix $B$ is given by $B^* e_i$, similarly, the $i$th column  $B$ is given by $B e_i$.

$\langle e_i, A^* A e_j \rangle = \langle A e_i,  A e_j \rangle$

$\langle e_i, A A^* e_j \rangle = \langle A^* e_i,  A^* e_j \rangle$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $A A^*=(\langle r_i,r_j\rangle )$ (Recall the definition of matrix multiplication).